# sed - replace string with equal number of characters

Tags: regex, sed

I have a text file in which I want to replace a string with a new string, and then add or remove spaces to make them the same number of characters. For example, I want to replace

```
string             .10
```

with

```
longer_string      .10
```

In essence I need to replace 'string', and then have the '.10' in the correct column, regarldess of the number of characters in the replacement string.

Comment: Hi @ericvb86 you mean something like this `sed -e 's/string/longer_string/g' file.txt`?

Comment: you could use replacement of ed or a vim script to do that otherwise you coud make a script that is regardless of replacement string's size match string's size to match/replace needed spaces regardless of diff size.

Comment: Re alexscott's answer: yes, I was going to say that this looks like more of a job for vi/vim than sed. Search for string (`/^string`), vim-replace with longer-string (`Rlonger-string<ESC>`). I don't know the exact vimscript code for this; you'd need to research: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)#Vim_script.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt) to do the replacement, and then perhaps re-align the columns with [`column`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html)?

```
cat input.txt | sed 's/string/longer_string/g' | column -t
```

Comment: Note `cat file | sed` has a UUoC. Better `sed '...' file .

Comment: What's with the UFLA? Personally, I like illustrative examples to flow left to right :)

Comment: Not sure what is the UFLA :D The UUoC is http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html : )

Answer (score 1):

You can print the line and append a carriage return; then, print the new line:

```
while IFS= read -r line;
do 
   echo -ne "$line\r"
   echo -ne "longer_string"
done < file
```

So in your file it would be:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do echo -ne "$line\r"; echo -ne "longer_string"; done < file
longer_string      .10
```

Note this works fine if the replacement string is longer than the original. For the opposite, we may need to do some extra steps.

Answer (score 0):

Sed is the wrong tool for the job here.

What you need is:

1. Split the words to work on ("string" & ".10") and store them in variables
2. Find the length of the leftmost component
3. Modify "string"
4. Print the modified strings in fixed width columns

Here goes:

```
# 1
str="string             .10"
a=$(echo "$str" | awk '{print $1}')
b=$(echo "$str" | awk '{print $2}')

# 2
# note the use of `echo -n` to avoid n+1 errors with `wc`. It does not change anything here because we're subtracting anyway, but if you play around it might bite you.
str_length=$(echo -n "$str" | wc -c)
b_length=$(echo -n "$b" | wc -c)
leftmost_length=$(( $str_length - $b_length ))

# 3
a="longer_${a}"

# 4
printf "%-${leftmost_length}s %-10s\n" "$a" "$b"
#   longer_string       .10
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/string(.*)/\nlonger_string\1\n&/;ta;:a;s/\n(\S)(.*\n)./\1\n\2/;ta;s/\n.*\n(.*)/\1/' file
```

This replaces `string` with `longer_string` and then appends the original line to the updated one (newlines are prepended to the old and new strings). Then characters are removed from the appended line until the end of the new string is matched. The spaces (less the introduced newline) from the old line then replace the remainder of the amended line.